# line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `

Tags: bash

I want to run a bash script as follows

```
#!/bin/sh

for model in (`cat list.txt`); do

    echo $model
    .....
    ......
done
```

I ran the code using command bash script.sh. However, I am still getting an error as

```
'cript.sh: line 3: `for model in (`cat list.txt`); do
```

Please let me know how I can run it.

Comment: First glance suggests `(\`cat list.txt\`)` should be `$(cat list.txt)`.

Comment: @Guest Your suggestion fixes a different syntax error, but it is wrong, too: see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: I am confused now. What should be the final syntax? Pls. help.